# How to implement ES6 javascript singleton function in base class

Tags: javascript, singleton, es6-class

I want dynamically load css into HTML in base class. This is sample:

```
export class base {
  constructor(divId) {

  }

  loadCss_SingletonFunc(cssText) {
    // load css into html page. But how to make sure it loads once.
  }
}

export class Hello extends base {
  constructor(divId) {

    const css1 = 'bla bla 1';
    const css2 = 'bla bla 2';

    super(divId);

    this.loadCss_SingletonFunc(css1);
    this.loadCss_SingletonFunc(css2);

  }
}

let a = new Hello('div1');

// Don't load same css 2 times in a page!!!
let b = new Hello('div2');
```

How to make sure 2 objects load same css into HTML only once?

Comment: Check if the CSS is already present, and if not, load it.

Comment: How to check css already loaded? Singleton method possible?